# How to see in fiddler what is posted to server

Tags: post, httpwebrequest, http-post, fiddler, httpwebresponse

I installed fiddler and made a GET request. It gives me what is returned from the server in header and cookies etc. Now I want to know the way to check (using fiddler) what is being posted to the server when I post a form (with some values in text boxes using firefox or any browser). Remember I am not seeking to know the way to compose a post request in fiddler. I want to know what browser sends to the server. Actually compose a post request is not working and it returns that same page which I post, so I want to know what browser is doing which I am unable to do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @nrathaus How can I see post request made using IE in Fiddler. Can you help me little more?

Comment: Open Fiddler, does it show any error? no? great, open IE, browse a site, that is it, it should work

Comment: I did the same, but fiddler shows no session when I open any site in IE. Do I need to do some thing more?

Comment: I think @nrathaus is confusing Firebug and other web developer tools with Fiddler.  You can use the "Inspectors" tab in Fiddler.  The top half is the request, so items like the Headers, WebForms, Cookies, Raw, JSON, and XML can be inspected depending on the type of request.

Comment: @ernie I can understand, I can check that all in "Inspectors" tab. But what? I made a Post request in IE then can fiddler show me IE session. I am unable to see that. Surely I can compose a post request in fiddler, but it fails to upload information to server. So I want to know what actually browser (IE or Firefox) is doing when it is posting a form.

Comment: No, @nrathaus, Fiddler works with every browser and virtually all mobile devices.

Comment: You'll need to find the actual request on the left, select it, then from the Inspector's tab, select the correct sub-tab, depending on how you submitted the data.

Answer (score 3):

Click on the request that you wish to see in Fiddler, right click and select "Decode Selected Sessions".

Answer (score 1):

If you're saying: "I don't see any traffic in Fiddler's Web Sessions list when sending a POST from Internet Explorer", you should follow the troubleshooting steps listed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/httpfiddler/SsZnGxdxklg

If the target page is HTTPS, you need to ensure that you enable HTTPS decryption or you won't see anything other than the `CONNECT` tunnel through which HTTPS traffic flows.

Otherwise, if you do see the POST in the Web Sessions list, double-click it to activate the Inspectors tab. Use the `Web Forms` tab or the the `Raw` tab to see the data posted from the client application.

You might want to watch the Fiddler tutorial videos to quickly get up to speed on how to use Fiddler: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLvmaC-XMqeBbw72l2G7FG7CntDTErjbHc